# Sort a linked list, handling pairs as a single item

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on this challenge:

> Sort a Linked list in increasing order by considering two nodes as a two digit number. (in place sorting)
>
> 4 ≤ *n* ≤ 1000
>
> The length of the linked list is always even.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> Input
>   1→3→4→2→1→2
>
> Output
>   1→2→1→3→4→2
>
> Explanation:
>   12 > 13 > 42
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> Input
>   1→3→0→3
>
> Output
>   0→3→1→3

Here is my linked list template implementation; which anyone can start coding:

```
 class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.next = None

 class Linkedlist():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self,x):
        t = Node(x)
        t.next = self.head
        self.head = t

    def display(self):
        p = self.head
        while p != None:
            print(p.data)
            p=p.next

    def sort(self):
        curr = self.head
        # your logic here

m = Linkedlist()
m.add(1)
m.add(3)
m.add(4)
m.add(2)
m.add(1)
m.add(2)
m.display()
```

Which is the algorithm to sort the pairs in a linked list (in place), and how can I code it?

Comment: What were your attemps/approaches? Do you need to implement your own linked list or do you need to use an implementation from a given library( (like llist)?

Comment: @mephisto need to implement my own, i am not getting idea how to do it in o(n)^2 time complexity

Comment: o(n^2) is the slowest complexity

Comment: How is the "linked list" implemented? Given the information exclusively in your post, do you think theres enough information to provide an answer? How would you answer it?

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy i know but it is impossible to do it inplace in 0(n) time complexity

Comment: @ Sayse the basic prerequisite code has been added on the post .please have a look

Comment: im working on it right now for you

Comment: The `add` method seems to *prepend* values to the list, so in the code you are not reproducing the list you described in the question, but its inverse.

Comment: look at my updated, answer

Answer (score 1):

First write a function that accepts a linked list of single digit nodes and merges each pair of adjacent single digit nodes into a linked list of half as many nodes, where each node contains a double digit number.

Then sort the resulting linked list using bubble sort, which is O(n^2), or mergesort, which is O(nlogn).

Then, if need be, write a third function that takes apart the double digit nodes and creates a new list of twice as many single digit nodes.

Doing it with two or three functions like this will really simplify the sort.

Comment: BTW, a linked list and bubble sort will be an order of magnitude slower than a builtin list and builtin timsort.

Comment: You might find this interesting.  It's a pure python linked list class: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/linked-list/

Comment: your intuition seems convincing .i appreciate your effort .keep helping the community.but can we do it on the same input linked list ,rather than taking anothe rlinked list for operation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your current code will not generate list 1→3→4→2→1→2, but its inverse. This is because your definition of the `add` method will *prepend* the given value to the list.

To make `add` work correctly, it should first find the last node in the list, and append the new node after it. As this is not a very efficient method to add many values to a list, I would suggest to also define `add` as a Node method, and to allow chaining `add` calls. That way you can add many values in one chained expression without being inefficient.

Also, as you will need to compare values of *pairs*, it makes sense to make a method on `Node` that will return the value of the pair formed by that node and the next in the list.

Finally, for the `sort` algorithm itself, you could reduce the list to its first pair only (which is then obviously sorted), and treat the rest as a separate list of unsorted nodes. Then extract a pair at a time from the unsorted list, and find the right place to inject it in the main list, so that it remains sorted.

This process represents *O(n²)* time complexity on average and in the worst case. The best case is *O(n)*, which occurs when the list is originally sorted in reverse order.

Here is how that could look:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.data = val
        self.next = None

    # Easy chaining: defining this method on a Node as well
    def add(self, val):
        node = Node(val)
        node.next = self.next
        self.next = node
        return node

    # Define how the value of a pair is calculated
    def pairvalue(self):
        return self.data * 10 + self.next.data

class Linkedlist():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, val):
        # Corrected method: addition should be at the end of the list
        node = Node(val)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else: # Look for the last node in the list
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next:
                curr = curr.next
            # ...and append the new node after it
            curr.next = node
        return node # Allow for chaining

    def display(self):
        p = self.head
        while p:
            print(p.data,  end= "→")
            p = p.next
        print("NIL")

    def sort(self):
        if not self.head:
            return
        # Reduce list to just its first pair
        # The remainder is a temporary "todo" list
        todo = self.head.next.next
        self.head.next.next = None

        while todo:
            pair = todo # The pair that will be added to the sorted list
            todo = todo.next.next
            val = pair.pairvalue()
            if val < self.head.pairvalue():
                # The pair is a minimum: prepend it
                pair.next.next = self.head
                self.head = pair
            else:
                curr = self.head.next # odd index
                # Find insertion point in sorted list
                while curr.next and curr.next.pairvalue() < val:
                    curr = curr.next.next
                # Perform insertion
                pair.next.next = curr.next
                curr.next = pair

m = Linkedlist()
m.add(1).add(3).add(4).add(2).add(1).add(2)
m.display() # original list
m.sort()
m.display() # final list
```

The output:

```
1→3→4→2→1→2→NIL
1→2→1→3→4→2→NIL
```